# Creating own marker with annotations in Eclipse-Plugin?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, annotations, jface, marker

I want to create a marker with own annotations within a PlugIn using the common Eclipse Editor and not adding an own editor. The markers will be set when an action is performed;

I read some stuff about markers in an own editor, but not in the common editor. Has anyone an idea? 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessarily all that difficult... Have a look at these [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/nonty/l0043-interfacing-to-eclipse-standard-views) from a course I have run on numerous occations.

Answer (score 0):

Markers can be created on a Resource (file/folder), using IResource.createMarker(). You don't need an editor for that. The existing editors should be able to display the markers on the resource.